# Flutter Hot Reload button is not active

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using Android Studio and recently installed Flutter but the hot reload button disabled

I deleted android studio also Flutter plugin and reinstall them again but still not working

see the screen shot for the button also result of Flutter Doctor if that help

https://ibb.co/HhjZRrR
https://ibb.co/h1gsMXb

Comment: I have the same flutter doctor result but I am actually able to hot reload on android studio

Answer (score 0):

The Android license agreements are mandatory before development, accept them by doing `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and then try running your app.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED finally I noticted that Flutter not support operating system Q beta, I choose oreo

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're running your app in release mode. That's what happened to me.